# Replacing vue.js template with setInterval

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been trying to refresh the content of a div at a given interval using vue.js, but up until now have had little if no success. Here's what I have at this point:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#feature',
    template: '<div id={{content}}></div>',
    data:
        featureList: [{
            content: 'a'
        }, {
            content: 'b'
        }, {
            content: 'c'
        }]
    }
});
```

On my html, I've the following:

```
<div id="feature"></div>
```

My approach here is to iterate through this array and replace *content* in the template at a given interval. The problem is that I'm not sure how to do it.

This is what I tried as an alternative to having an array in *data*: making *content* a computed property with a setter function, with a single string in *data*. Like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#feature',
  template: '<div id={{content}}></div>',
  data: {
    content: 'a'
  },
  computed: {
    setTemplate: {
      set: function(newValue) {
      var values= newValue
      this.content = values
      }
    }
  }
});

vm.setTemplate = 'c'
```

(jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/0r6cf4uf/15/))

Now, how do I go from here? How do I change *content* at a certain interval from a set of given strings?

Comment: I'd use a `ready` method in the component so trigger the `setInterval` and update `data` within it.

Comment: I guess that would work yes, I may try that approach too. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can use the [lifecycle hooks](http://vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#Instance_Lifecycle) for this, specifically the `ready` hook:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#feature',
    template: '<div id={{content}}>{{content}}</div>',
    data: {
        content: 'hi there',
        features: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        currentIndex: 0
    },

    created: function() {
        var self = this
        setTimeout(function cycle() {
            self.content = self.features[self.currentIndex++]
            self.currentIndex %= self.features.length
            setTimeout(cycle, 2000)
        }, 2000)
    }
});
```

See [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0r6cf4uf/16/).

Comment: It think this is it. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you've got any further questions, let me know :)

Comment: I may have, thanks! :-) Still going through the code and the documentation on lifecycle hooks